# How to declare Int as foreign key in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

So per default its like this:

```
public class MyEntity{

   private int id;

   @OneToOneOrWhatever
   private MyOtherEntity other;

}
```

You can make a relation simply by adding the object to it. But in my case, loading the whole object with eager loading would be simply overkill. I just want to retrieve the id of "MyOtherEntity" , nothing else.
Is something like this:

```
public class MyEntity{

    private int id;

   @SomeFancyAnnotationToRelateTo(MyOtherEntity.class)
   private int foreignKeyId;

}
```

possible?

Comment: Just make the `@OneToOne` a lazy one by setting `fetch` to `LAZY`.

Comment: You should create a query in your repository that will fetch the Id of the related object.

Comment: If you really don't want a reference between MyEntity and MyOtherEntity, then just use the annotation @Column(name="columnName") like you would any other property that doesn't map to a class. Though you'll then need to make queries to retrieve the data when you want it

Comment: A Java "int" is never a FK. This is an object-oriented tech, not the mapping of random integers

Answer (score 0):

This may do it.

```
public class MyEntity{
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "myTypeId")
    private MyType myType;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `FetchType.LAZY`.

```
public class MyEntity{

   private int id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private MyOtherEntity other;

}
```

And then you can access the id via `myEntity.getMyOtherEntity().getId();`

Some explanation:
If lazy-loading is set on a property of an entity, when Hibernate loads that entity from the DB, instead of creating the appropriate property Object and loading all of its properties from its own table, instead it creates a 'proxy' for that object and stores only the id in it.

When you later try to access any of the properties of this proxied object at the first time, it recognizes that the object is not initialized and does load the object.

They usually say the object will be loaded when you access it at the first time.
But the 'id' field is an exception. It is already present in the proxy object too! (It's quite logical: in order to load the whole entity from DB you need the id anyway).
So as long as you access only the id field the other fields won't be loaded. (there will be no access to OtherEntity's DB table)

Although a proxy object is created plus some additional JPA/hibernate magic happens in the background, it's still the most efficient way to access the id field. (Also, if you later still some other fields, they will be loaded automatically)